# Windows Phone 8 Control to select multiple

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am currently making a windows phone application for `windows phone 8`.
I was wondering if there is a control or library which adds a control that allows you to show multiple items and have a button to increment or decrement next to each item.
for example

```
Item1  - 3  +
Item2  - 0  +
```

Any ideas or different ways to overcome/solve this would be appreciated

Comment: I don't believe there is a native control in windows phone that allows this functionality. You could achieve this by using a listview and a data template with two buttons. One for + and one for - .

Comment: ill try it out with that listview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from my comment here is some code that should get you started. I'm not aware if you are using mvvm or code behind so I can't show how exactly the button actions would be hooked up but if you tell me I can expand upon this more.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyBinding}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>              
        <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/> 
            <Button x:Name="Decrement" Content="-"/> // Hook this button up to an action
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Number}"/>
            <Button x:Name="Increment" Content="+"/> // Hook this button up another action
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: i am unable to put a listview in it, even from code, do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: You are going to have to show more code from your xaml. I don't exactly understand what u mean when you say you are "unable to put a listview in it"

Comment: Do listview also exist for windows phone 8, not 8.1?

Comment: The Error i am getting: Error 1 The name "ListView" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"

Comment: Yes, ListView exists in windows phone 8. See here [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listview.aspx) . Is this a Windows 8 phone silverlight project? if so I believe the equivalents are ListBox or LongListSelector

Comment: Yes, its a silverlight project for windows phone 8, LongListSelector does exist.
Never used it before, although you say i should be able to add buttons to it.

Comment: Yes, You can add buttons to the LongListSelector ItemTemplate. Similar to the above code